# Cucumber JSON : Generate separate JSON file for each scenario in cucumber-report JSON format

Tags: java, json, cucumber

I am generation JSON file to generate cucumber-report as per format mentioned from hybrid automation framework.
However, want to create JSON file for each scenario. Below is the code

Main.java

```
package com.demo.jdbc;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class jsonCucumber {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
    //CucumberJSONGenerator3 cucumberJSONGenerator = new CucumberJSONGenerator3();
    //CucumberJSONGenerator2 cucumberJSONGenerator = new CucumberJSONGenerator2();
    CucumberJSONGenerator cucumberJSONGenerator = new CucumberJSONGenerator();
   
    // Add a scenario with tags
    String[] tags = {"tag1", "tag2"};
    cucumberJSONGenerator.addScenario("My Scenario", tags);
    cucumberJSONGenerator.addStep("Given I navigate to the homepage", "passed");
    cucumberJSONGenerator.addStep("When I click the login button", "passed");
    cucumberJSONGenerator.addStep("Then I should see the dashboard", "failed");

    cucumberJSONGenerator.executionFinish("cucumber_report.json");
    //cucumberJSONGenerator.executionFinish();
        
        
     // Add a scenario without tags
        cucumberJSONGenerator.addScenario("Another Scenario",new String[]{});
        cucumberJSONGenerator.addStep("Given I open the application", "passed");
        cucumberJSONGenerator.addStep( "When I enter my username", "passed");
        cucumberJSONGenerator.addStep( "And I enter my password", "passed");
        cucumberJSONGenerator.addStep( "Then I should be logged in", "passed");
      // cucumberJSONGenerator.executionFinish();
        
     cucumberJSONGenerator.executionFinish("cucumber_report1.json");
    }

}
```

CucumberJSONGenerator.java

```
package com.demo.jdbc;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CucumberJSONGenerator {

private JsonObject cucumberReport;
private JsonArray cucumberFeatures;
private JsonObject cucumberFeature;
private JsonArray cucumberElements;
private JsonObject cucumberElement;
private JsonArray cucumberSteps;
private JsonObject cucumberStep;

public CucumberJSONGenerator() {
    cucumberReport = new JsonObject();
    cucumberFeatures = new JsonArray();
}

public void addScenario(String scenarioName, String[] tags) {
    
    cucumberFeature = new JsonObject();
    cucumberFeature.addProperty("name", scenarioName);
    
    if (tags == null) {
        tags = new String[0];
    }
    
    cucumberFeature.add("tags", generateTagsArray(tags));
    cucumberElements = new JsonArray();
    cucumberFeature.add("elements", cucumberElements);
    cucumberSteps = new JsonArray();
    cucumberElement = new JsonObject();
    cucumberElement.add("steps", cucumberSteps);
    cucumberElements.add(cucumberElement);
    cucumberFeatures.add(cucumberFeature);
}

public void addStep(String stepName, String status) {
    cucumberStep = new JsonObject();
    cucumberStep.addProperty("name", stepName);
    cucumberStep.addProperty("result", status);
    cucumberSteps.add(cucumberStep);
}

public void executionFinish(String filePath) {
    try {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        JsonObject currentScenario = cucumberFeatures();
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i < cucumberFeatures.size(); i++) {
            
            JsonObject cucumberReport = new JsonObject();
            cucumberReport.addProperty("name", "Cucumber Report");
            cucumberReport.addProperty("description", "This is a sample Cucumber report generated using Java.");
            cucumberReport.addProperty("keyword", "Feature");

            JsonArray features = new JsonArray();
            features.add(cucumberFeatures.get(i));
            cucumberReport.add("features", features);

            String scenarioName = cucumberFeatures.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("name").getAsString();
            String fileName = scenarioName.replaceAll(" ", "_") + ".json";
            String fileWithPath = filePath + fileName;

            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileWithPath);
            writer.write(gson.toJson(cucumberReport));
            writer.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private JsonObject cucumberFeatures() {
    return cucumberFeatures.get(cucumberFeatures.size() - 1).getAsJsonObject();
}

private JsonArray generateTagsArray(String[] tags) {
    JsonArray tagsArray = new JsonArray();
    for (String tag : tags) {
        JsonObject tagObject = new JsonObject();
        tagObject.addProperty("name", tag);
        tagsArray.add(tagObject);
    }
    return tagsArray;
}
```

}

With above code three files are generating below three files

1. cucumber_report.jsonMy_Scenario.json
2. cucumber_report1.jsonAnother_Scenario.json
3. cucumber_report1.jsonMy_Scenario.json

I want only two files instead of three.

1. cucumber_report.jsonMy_Scenario.json
2. cucumber_report1.jsonAnother_Scenario.json

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With below code I can generate separate JSON files

```
    public void saveJSONRport() {
        // Function to save JSON file. It will create separate JSON file for each
        // scenario
         Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
            JsonArray elementsArray = new JsonArray();
            for (JsonObject elementObject : elementList) {
                elementsArray.add(elementObject);
            }
            jsonObject.add("elements", elementsArray);
            ArrayList<JsonObject> jsonListArray = new ArrayList<JsonObject>();
            jsonListArray.add(jsonObject);
            String json = gson.toJson(jsonListArray);

            // Save the JSON in a folder
            // Assuming folder path is "target/cucumber-reports"
            File folder = new File("target/cucumber-reports/json_files");
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                folder.mkdirs();
            }
            String fileName = "cucumber_report_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".json";
            File file = new File(folder, fileName);
            try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file)) {
                fileWriter.write(json);
                fileWriter.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            System.out.println(" file - " + fileName );
            // Reset jsonObject and Array to prepare for next scenario
//          jsonObject = new JsonObject();
//          elementList = new ArrayList<JsonObject>();
    }
}
```